# laravel обработать сторонний Exception

Tags: php, laravel

Как можно обработать Exception стороннего пакета? Допустим вылеатет

```
"exception": "Tymon\\JWTAuth\\Exceptions\\TokenInvalidException
```

Как можно его обработать в своих эксепшенах? допустим создам TokenInvalidException с таким же именем, но как мне передать исключение в него?

Comment: Зачем создавать exception с таким же именем? Можно же просто сделать use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException и обрабатываеть его в try catch

Comment: @Григорий , не хочу трайкетчами засирать код)

Comment: Насколько я знаю есть только один способ обработать исключение - try catch. Если вы создадите свое исключение, его все равно нужно обрабатывать. Либо я не понял ваш вопрос.

Comment: @Григорий, необязательно, в ларавеле свой обработчик исключений, и можно внутри него обработать любое исключение, или так же создать свое через php artisan:make exception , и прописав метод render() это и будет являтся обработкой, без всяких try catch )

Comment: В языке php исключения можно обработать только через try catch и то, что laravel, дает вам свою обертку которая в итоге все равно вызывает try catch не отменяет этот факт. Касаемо же вашего вопроса,  вы можете в методе render класса App\Exceptions\Handler  написать if ($exception instanceof TokenInvalidException) return response()->view('errors.custom', [], 500);

Comment: @Григорий , что приведет к засиранию этого файла

Comment: Совсем не писать код не получиться) А создание дополнительного файла с таким же именем вас не смущает? К тому же вам все равно придется где то ловить первое исключение TokenInvalidException и делать  throw CustomException. Ну и писать метод render в Exception имхо плохо